# Thymeleaf validation: .hasErrors does not trigger

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate input values of a form fieldset and to make Thymeleaf show some error message when invalid inputs occur. But somehow the following Thymeleaf command never gets resolved in the right way:

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('itemId')}" th:errors="{*all}">Name Error</p>
```

More information about my environment won't hurt I guess:

Based on the **Spring GS-Guide *"Validating Form Input"*** I implemented the relevant controller method as followed:

**Controller:**

```
[...]
        @RequestMapping(value = "/explorer/optaResultRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String optaResultRequestPOST(
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            ModelMap model, 
            @ModelAttribute("request") @Valid SomeRequest userRequest,
            final BindingResult bindingResult)
    {

        /* To destroy existing "request" attribute: */
        model.clear();

        /* Check for invalid values: */
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bindingResult.getAllErrors().size(); i++)
            {
                log.info(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(i).getObjectName());
                log.info(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(i).getCode());
                log.info(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(i).toString());
            }

            /* Refill the model with a new, empty "request" attribute. */
            model.addAttribute("currRequest", userRequest);
            model.addAttribute("request", new SomeRequest());

            return "mypage";
        }

        // Process valid request... 
    }
```

When I submit an invalid form input to the controller, it runs into the if clause as desired, that way prints the log.infos and returns the same page again (mypage) - but the mentioned Thymeleaf command **does not show anything**.

**Console:**

```
 2015-07-22 16:22:28.151  INFO 6896 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Controller   :
 request
 2015-07-22 16:22:28.151  INFO 6896 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Controller   :
 NotEmpty
 2015-07-22 16:22:28.151  INFO 6896 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Controller   :
 Field error in object 'request' on field 'itemId':
        rejected value [];
        codes [NotEmpty.request.itemId,NotEmpty.itemId,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty];
        arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
                  codes [request.itemId,itemId]; 
                  arguments []; 
                  default message [itemId]]; 
        default message [may not be empty]
```

The mypage.html looks like this (simplified and shortened of cause):

**mypage.html**

```
<form action="#" th:object="${request}" th:action="@{/mypage}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <!--  ItemId -->

        <div>
          <label>ItemId</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="text" th:field="*{itemId}" th:placeholder=
          "${currRequest.itemId}" />
        </div>

        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('itemId')}" th:errors="{*all}">Name Error</p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

---

So I got two questions:

1. **Obviously: How to display the error messages?**
2. I would really like to go deeper into debugging - but unfortunately I do not know how to debug Thymeleaf and (Java) MVC (using STS) in general. I only managed to include detailed loggings of everything.
   **But i.e. how do I track the current/final value of Thymeleaf variables like *#fields.hasErrors()*?**

Big thanks in advance for your efforts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, the combination *model.clear();* and *model.addAttribute("request", new SomeRequest());* was the reason.

I wasn't quite aware of that the Thymeleaf engine gets invoked *after* the **return** statement and so it can only access the new, empty request object, which has no invalid attributes.

On the other hand the logger inside the POST-method accesses the bindingResult-Object and so it can print validation information independently of what happens to the model and its attributes inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your * is in the wrong spot

**edit**

`<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('itemId')}" th:errors="*{all}">Name Error</p>`

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand your answer. By * do you mean the expression "{*all}"? Where/What shall be the right spot for it then? I've also tried other expressions like "{request}" and "{.itemId}" but none of these worked either. And why did you post "Name Error"?!? "Name Error" in the html file is nothing more than plain text.